# confusion about work done to move between two points just outside a charged conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, conductors

When charge isn't uniformly distributed on the surface of a conductor, the field outside differs in magnitude but is everywhere perpendicular to the surface.
Suppose I move a test charge between two points just outside the conductor, a distance r from its body that is so close to its body that the field is always perpendicular, then according to this reasoning work will not be done by the electric field. However, if we take another path, that is, we go right towards the conductor and inside then we go outside just right outward from the conducting body to reach the second point, since the magnitude of the field is different, work will be done! How is this possible?

Comment: You do realise that *elecric potential energy* is a state function*, right?

Comment: @Gert the question is good, read it again

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the point that the electric field strength is equal to (minus) the potential gradient.

Where the electric field is stronger you will have to move less of a distance $\Delta x_{\rm large \, E}$ to produce a certain change in potential $\Delta V$ as compared with the distance $\Delta x_{\rm small \, E}$ when the field is weaker.

$\Delta V = E_{\rm large}\,\Delta x_{\rm large \, E} = E_{\rm small}\,\Delta x_{\rm small\, E}$ with $E_{\rm large} > E_{\rm small}$ and $\Delta x_{\rm large \, E}<\Delta x_{\rm small\, E}$  and the products are equal.

Put another way, the spacing of the equipotential lines/surface is smaller in regions where the electric field is larger.

Here is a sketch of electric field lines (red lines) and equipotential lines (blue dashes) to illustrate this idea.

[image]

With $aa' = bb'$ and the $bb'$ field being larger then the $aa'$, in terms of potential difference $\Delta V_{\rm bb'} > \Delta V_{\rm aa'}$.

On the other hand $\Delta V_{\rm cc'} = \Delta V_{\rm dd'}$ because $E_{\rm cc'} > E_{\rm dd'}$ and $cc' < dd'$

Work done path $aa'b'ba$ is non-zero whereas work done path $cc'd'dc$ is zero.

Comment: But since the distance from the surface of the conductor is the same r, this means work will not balance.

Comment: what if you move parallel to the surface at a constant dx? then, when you instead move into the conductor from that same dx and out to that same dx, $E_{small}dx\ne E_{large}dx$, that is, they would seem to be different.

Comment: I believe that the gradient of E will explain why, at constant dx, the two changes in potential cancel. That is, E is not constant across dx. But I am not sure about this.

Comment: I also thought the same way but I wasn't sure.

Comment: But I think if this was true then the work to go in a closed loop around the conductor will be non zero, do you agree or am I missing something? This would be true unless the electric field adjusted itself in some manner that made the work zero.

Comment: @AhmedSamir I do not see why that would be the case

Comment: I used the example of the grounded infinite conducting plane with a positive point charge on one side and used the method of images to get the electric field in the direction of x just a distance y above the conducting plane and I think the result asserts that what you said was true, that is, a small change in y will produce a parallel electric field @Wolphram jonny